# Prove that an infinite cardinal $\kappa$ is singular if an only if it is the sum of less than $\kappa$ smaller cardinals.

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I don't understand some passages of following demostration which is present in "Introduction to Set Theory" by Karel Hrbacek and Thomas Jech

[image]

So in the first step I don't understand why $\kappa=\bigcup_{\nu\in\theta}\alpha_\nu=\bigcup(\alpha_\nu-\bigcup_{\xi<\nu}\alpha_\xi)$ -furthermore the symbol "$-$" correspond to the difference between the sets $\alpha_\nu$ and $\bigcup_{\xi<\nu}\alpha_\xi$?- and why the $A_\nu$'s are mutually disjoint; then instead in the second step I don't understad why it must be $\kappa=sup_{\alpha<\lambda}\kappa_\alpha$ and I 
I haven't been able to find by transfinite recursion a subsequence which is increasing and has limit $\kappa$. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\kappa=\bigcup_{\nu\in\theta}\alpha_\nu$ holds because $\alpha_\nu$ is a cofinal sequence in $\kappa$. This is also equal to $$\bigcup_{\nu\in\theta}\left(\alpha_\nu\setminus\bigcup_{\xi<\nu}\alpha_\xi\right)$$ because of reasons that have nothing to do with ordinals, in plain English this notation is saying "instead of taking $\alpha_\nu$ let's take all elements of $\alpha_\nu$ that we haven't already put into our union". This does not change the union in the end since every $\eta\in\bigcup_{\nu\in\theta}\alpha_\nu$ is also in one $A_\nu$, namely the one whose index is the least $\nu$ such that $\eta\in\alpha_\nu$. The $A_\nu$ are pairwise disjoint by construction, since to construct $A_\nu$ we're removing from $\alpha_\nu$ all the elements that are already in a smaller $A_\xi$, so they can't have any elements in common.

In the second step you know that $\kappa=\lambda\cdot\sup_{\alpha<\lambda}\kappa_\alpha$ by a previous theorem, but $\lambda\cdot\sup_{\alpha<\lambda}\kappa_\alpha=\max\{\lambda,\sup_{\alpha<\lambda}\kappa_\alpha\}$ by basic properties of cardinal multiplication, and since $\lambda<\kappa=\max\{\lambda,\sup\kappa_\alpha\}$ the only option left is $\kappa=\sup\kappa_\alpha$.

Finally you know that $\kappa_\alpha$ is a sequence unbounded in $\kappa$, so to find an increasing unbounded subsequence $(\kappa_{\alpha_i})$ you can proeed by induction as follows: Let $\kappa_{\alpha_0}=\kappa_0$. At successor stages if you have $\kappa_{\alpha_i}$ and you want to construct $\kappa_{\alpha_{i+1}}$ you can pick any $\kappa_\alpha>\kappa_{\alpha_i}$, which must exist since $\sup\kappa_\alpha=\kappa$. At a limit stage $\eta$ you have constructed $\kappa_{\alpha_i}$ for all $i<\eta$ and you want to construct $\kappa_{\alpha_\eta}$. There's two possibilities. Either $\sup_{i<\eta}\kappa_{\alpha_i}=\kappa$, so the sequence is complete and you're done, or $\sup_{i<\eta}\kappa_{\alpha_i}<\kappa$. In that case you can pick as $\kappa_{\alpha_\eta}$ any $\kappa_\alpha>\sup_{i<\eta}\kappa_{\alpha_i}$ (which against must exist since $\sup\kappa_\alpha=\kappa$).

Comment: Perhaps I managed to prove the first equality by transinite induction, but 
since the demonstration is too long for a comment I had to post another question: to follow the link
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3514881/how-to-prove-that-bigcup-nu-theta-alpha-nu-bigcup-nu-theta-alpha-n
Is my reasoning correct?